# How to pull stock exchange names for a list of tickers, bloomberg?

Tags: data

How to pull stock exchange names for a list of stocks with tickers, on bloomberg? Please advise the steps so as to paste the list of tickers without having to type tickers one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Bloomberg Excel Add-In:

```
=BDP(TICKER,"EQY_PRIM_SECURITY_PRIM_EXCH")
```

Comment: thank you, Emcor. will this give me the exchange symbols along with exchange names against ticker symbols on a global level?

Comment: I recommend you contact the Bloomberg HelpDesk for details (pressing the green key on the terminal twice).